# SwiftUI list: NSInternalInconsistencyException / invalid number of rows

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I have a view `CountriesListScreen`, to which I am passing a list of items.

```
struct CountriesListScreen: View {
  var listItems: CountriesListItems

  var body: some View {
    VStack {

      Section(header: CountriesListHeader()) {
        ForEach (listItems, id: \.name) { item in
            ...
        }
      }

    }
  }

}
```

This is what I am doing:

- I am first displaying `CountriesListScreen`, with 9 list items
- I then go to another view, where I perform an action, which modifies the list of items
- I then go back to `CountriesListScreen`, passing the new listItems object, which has now 5 items instead of 9

I am getting this `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, which I don't know how to solve:

> *** Assertion failure in -[_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView
> _Bug_Detected_In_Client_Of_UITableView_Invalid_Number_Of_Rows_In_Section:],
> UITableView.m:2471 2021-06-11 18:22:55.908398+0300
> iosApp[6525:5802640] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
> number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an
> existing section after the update (9) must be equal to the number of
> rows contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus
> the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
> 4 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
> that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

If I understand correctly, SwiftUI triggers the error, as it realizes that the list of items has changed, and the change hasn't happened within the view.

How can I safely, redraw the list with a different number of items, without having this error triggered?

**UPDATE: (giving more context)**

The views involved are 3:

1. the parent of `CountriesListScreen`, let's call it `MainView`, which references an `ObservedObject`, which has `listItems` as a property
2. `CountriesListScreen`, which receives `listItems` as a parameter from its parent
3. a third view, which performs an action that modifies the `listItems` (and hence the `ObservedObject`), triggering an update of the `MainView`

Comment: "I then go to another view, where I perform an action, which modifies the list of items”, how can you modify variable from within struct, without make using of property wrappers in swiftUI? It shouldn’t even compile.

Comment: Let's bring some clarity. There are 3 views involved:
1) the parent of `CountriesListScreen`, which we can call it `MainView`, which references an ObservedObject, which has `listItems` as a property
2) `CountriesListScreen`, which receives `listItems` as a parameter from its parent
3) the view I called "another view", which makes the modification to the listItem, hence triggering an update of the MainView

Comment: What type is `CountriesListItems`? Is it a type alias to an array, or is it a Class/Struct ?

Comment: `CountriesListItems` is an array of objects